# How to use where clause if value from another table is null

Tags: sql-server

I think this maybe a simple question, but I kind of stuck for a non-SQL Developer.

Example my select statement is like this.

```
Select ID, Year
From Table A
Where Year = (Select Year from table B)
```

If `year` from `table B` `is null`, I want to return all rows from `table A` else filter by value from `table B`.

Now what happen is when table B is null there is no rows return from table A.

Edited: There is only one row in Table B, and Value year from table B can be manually control to be null or not null.

Comment: I think we need to know under what circumstances year would be null in table B. There is no parameter nor linking field involved, maybe something is missing from the above?

Comment: Hi I have edited my question, maybe can clarify a bit ?

Comment: You have some answers to try below.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use as `Where Year = (Select Year from table B)`
Because if TableB has more than one records, the above query will return an error.

Use this query instead;

```
SELECT TA.ID, TA.Year
FROM TableA TA
LEFT JOIN TableB TB ON TB.Year = TA.Year
```

Updated:
According to the update you made to the question, the query will be;

```
SELECT TA.ID, TA.Year
FROM TableA TA
WHERE TA.Year= (Select Year from table B)
OR (Select Year from table B) IS NULL
```

Comment: While a useful suggestion it doesn't solve their problem.

Comment: @DaleBurrell why not? This will return all the data in TableA even though the TableB does not have any data. Isn't it?

Comment: The question states either all rows OR the rows for the year in question - they don't want all the rows all the time. To be fair its not clear under what circumstances it would be one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd to have a specification that a table will always have exactly one row. It's not invalid, but it's unusual.

If table B were empty, if it contained zero rows, then what should the query return? An error? An empty set? or all rows from A?

If table B contained more than one row, what should be returned? An error? An empty set? Rows from A that matched one of the non-NULL values of year from B? All rows from A?

Most often, its the edge cases and corner cases that spell out the specification... we expect the cases to be tested, we need to know what to test for... and then we can develop a query.

There are several query patterns that would satisfy the spec; the big differences are going to be those edge cases... table B is empty, or year column in table A is NULL.

I'd probably tend to go with something like this:

```
 SELECT a.id
      , a.year
   FROM ( SELECT MAX(b.year) AS year
            FROM table_b b
        ) v
   JOIN table_a a
     ON a.year <=> IFNULL(v.year,a.year)
```

SQL Fiddle demonstration http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44c277/1

---

If the question is actually about using the `WHERE` clause, then feel free to replace the keyword `ON` with `WHERE`.

*DOH!* Reviewing the question, it's asking about SQL Server, not MySQL. The syntax above is for MySQL.  For SQL Server, then something like this:

```
 SELECT a.id
      , a.year
   FROM ( SELECT MAX(b.year) AS year
            FROM table_b b
        ) v
   JOIN table_a a
     ON COALESCE(a.year,-1) = COALESCE(v.year,a.year,-1)
```

We are using `-1` as a special placeholder value, as a replacement for NULL, so the equality comparison will be satisfied. Without a special placeholder value, we'll have to incorporate some `IS NULL` conditional tests.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your inner query return single row only.

You can do this like.

```
SELECT ID, Year
FROM TableA
WHERE Year = 
             (
                 SELECT Year 
                 FROM TableB
             )
OR Year IS NULL
```

As far as your line "If year from table B is null, I want to return all rows from table A else filter by value from table B." is concerns, use the following query

```
SELECT ID, Year
FROM TableA
WHERE NVL(Year, '0') = (CASE WHEN (SELECT Year FROM TableB) IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT Year FROM TableB) ELSE NVL(Year, '0') END)
```

I did not test this query, but hopes that you will get the point here.

Answer (score -2):

use ISNULL and set the NULL as 0 like

Select ID, Year
From Table A
Where Year = (Select ISNULL(Year,0) from table B)

Hope this works!

Comment: I'm fairly certain this doesn't satisfy the specification, to return ALL rows in A when B.year is NULL.